pyinstaller exe terminates before completing program
I have sucessfully turned my file into an exe using python -m PyInstaller [path to your file] [args]
However the program terminates before it reaches the "would you like to add more data?" input. Additionally the program doesn't write to CSV. I suspect that this is because PyInstaller is a stripped down python library but I would have no idea how to solve this as the only other mention online was a stub.
Here is my code:
import csv

from gemini import OpenRouter

api_key = "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"

gemma_client = OpenRouter(api_key=api_key, model="google/gemma-7b-it:free")

data = []

num = 0
while True:
    num + 1
    article = input("Enter url: ")
    summary = gemma_client.create_chat_completion("Summarise findings of the following paper:"+article+". DONT USE DOTPOINTS, In the first line state of your response state whether it is an original work or not in the form OG:Yes or OG:Noo")
    OG = summary[0:13]
    summary = summary[13:]
    data.append([num, OG, summary])

    with open('data.csv', mode='w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerows(data)

    add_more = input("Do you want to add more data? (yes/no): ")
    if add_more.lower() != 'yes':
        break
    

The error tab closes too quick for me to fully read but it says something "traceback error".
I was expecting it to work.

Run your program in a preexisting shell window -- that way the window will stay open even after the program exits so you can read the error in full. (Once you've collected it, [edit] the error into your question as text)

BTW, did you mean to publish your API key in the question? (Note that edit history is public, and Stack Overflow is regularly scraped, so just removing the key through an edit or even deleting the question isn't enough to protect it -- you'll want to disable that key and generate a new one)
